# Do there exist languages with wh-prepositions?

Tags: syntax, linguistic-typology, list-of-languages, prepositions, wh-words

I can imagine a language where instead of "what did you put a toy on?" one says something like "whon did you put a toy?". Do such languages exist?

Comment: "Where did you put a toy" works, doesn't it? I think I've heard "where" described as a (pro-)preposition

Comment: "What did you put it there for?" = "Why did you put it there?"

Comment: @sumelic Seems to me that *where*, *there*, *when* are pro-PPs--which if you accept the notion of intransitive prepositions is skirting very close to pro-preposition.

Comment: English? "The dog of the man ran away" -> "Whose dog ran away?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

German does have something like this:
<sub>(list of abbreviations see below)</sub>

```
Wo-r-auf     hast du  ein Spielzeug gelegt?
where-ITF-on have you a   toy       put.PSTPTCP
Where did you put a toy on?

Wo-von   ernähren sich    Hasen?
where-of live.on  REFLPRN rabbits
What do rabbits live on?

Wo-nach     riecht das?
where-after smells that
What does this smell like?

Wo-durch      entsteht ein Tornado?
where-through develops a   tornado
Due to what does a tornado develop?
```

This is due to [Pied piping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement#Pied-piping): When wh-fronting an NP, you also have to move another element it goes with (like prepositions); this is often optional in English, but obligatory in German:

```
Sie hat sich    [mit  XYZ] getroffen
she has REFLPRN [with XYZ] meet.PSTPTCP
She met [with XYZ]
```

-->

```
[Mit  wem]     hat sie sich    __ getroffen?
[with who.DAT] has she REFLPRN __ meet.PSTPTCP
[With whom] did she meet __?
```

Leaving the preposition at its initial position after the NP it belongs to has moved to the front makes the sentence ungrammatical:

```
* [Wem    ] hat sie sich    mit  __ getroffen?
  [who.DAT] has she REFLPRN with __ meet.PSTPTCP
Who did she meet with?
```

The preposition *must* be moved to the front as well in order to make the wh-question grammatical. This is what is called pied piping.

When the questioned NP is not a person ("who"/"wer"), but an object ("what"/"was"):

```
Die Schüler  haben [mit XYZ]  experimentiert.
the students have  [with XYZ] experiment.PSTPTCP
The students experimented [with XYZ].

Du  hast ein Spielzeug [auf XYZ] gelegt.
you have a   toy       [on  XYZ] put.PSTPTCP
You put a toy [on XYZ].
```

you could colloquially say:

```
[Mit  was]       haben die Schüler  __ experimentiert?
[with what.DAT]  have  the students __ experiment.PSTPTCP
[What] did the students experiment with __?

[Auf was]  hast du  ein Spielzeug __ gelegt?  
[on  what] have you a   toy       __ put.PSTPTCP
[What] did you put a toy on __?
```

However, the "correct" form is turning the question word "was" into "wo" (literally "where", but it loses its local meaning and severes only as a basis to indicate the wh-word) and attaching the pied-piped preposition to it:

```
[Wo-mit]     haben die Schüler  __ experimentiert?
[where-with] have the  students __ experiment.PSTPTCP
What did the students experiment with __?

[Wo-r-auf]     hast du  ein Spielzeug __ gelegt?
[where-ITF-on] have you a   toy       __ put.PSTPTCP
What did you put a toy on __?
```

This results in a wh-word which is at the same time prepositional. It looks like "where" + preoposition, but as said, the "wo" has no local meaning in this context (that the "toy" example is about locality is only a coincidence; this is not indicated in the "wo" part), it behaves more like "w"+preposition where the "o" is only inserted for pronouncability, so I would guess this is exactly what you were looking for.

---

`ITF` [interfix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfix)
`PSTPTCP` past participle verb form
`REFLPRN` reflexive pronoun
`DAT` dative case

Comment: That's pretty much what I was looking for, thank you

Comment: English has these constructions too, though unlike German English has always confined them pretty much to formal/bureaucratic registers: *whereon/hereon/thereon*, *whereto/hereto/thereto*, *whereunder/hereunder/thereunder*, &c.

Comment: And Dutch uses "waar" ("where") as a prefix as well in the same way. It seems far too unlikely to just be a coincidence that German happens to have picked the vowel that turns the prefix into the German word for "where".

Comment: @hvd Sure, with the evidence from English and Dutch, it's not unlikely that it originated from "wo" as a question word for locality. What I meant was only that synchronically, this meaning is no longer transparent in that "worauf" as used in the toy sentence has no more inherent local meaning than "wo-" as used in "womit" does, in case this was the point of your concern.

Comment: @StoneyB: there's the famous example "Wherefore art thou Romeo"  from Shakespeare.

Comment: @sumelic Quite so--and "Never mind the whys and wherefores". Somehow how *wherefore* and *therefore* escaped into ordinary speech.

Comment: And how about *whither* and *whence*?

Comment: Actually, in PIE the word for "where" was "q̆or".

Answer (score 5):

My assumption from Turkish is that agglutinative languages have this property.

For example:

- *Oyuncağı **nereye** koydun?*

Word by word:

- *TheToy **whon** youput*

In Turkish "**Ne**" means *What*, but also is used as *wh*. **Ne** + **rede** means *in Where*, **Ne** + **den** means *for What*.

Answer (score 2):

Hindi kind of has this feature:

> किस (चीज़) पे खिलौना रखा?
>     *kis (cIz) pe khilonA rakhA?*
>     What did you put the toy on?
>
> किसने किया?
>     *kisne kiyA?*
>     Who did it?

किस is the oblique form of the word क्या (kyA) meaning "what".

Comment: The first Hindi i sentence will be " What (kis)  On (pe) Toy(khilona) You(*omitted*)  Put(rakha).  Should we take first two words as one?

Comment: @ARI I think I've seen it merged sometimes... but I'm not sure if it always is one word

Answer (score 1):

Preposition by definition means that it is a functional word put in front of another word (typically nominal in nature) that it modifies in some way.

The wh- type words are pronominal (or more precisely shifter-like) in their nature, thus they need to stand for full sense words, e.g. nouns (what/who) or adverbs (where/when/how).

Thus to have a wh- type preposition is sort of contradictory (to be honest, when I read the title, I thought you meant something like *"WH-prep table did you put the plate?"*, i.e. asking in which position towards the table the plate was put - beneath it, on it, next to it,...).

What you are referring to (Wh-on did you put the toy) would most likely not be analysed as preposition but just a simple contraction of two words/morphs that can exist apart but in this specific combination, they merge into a single unit. This obviously happens frequently with prepositions and pronouns, e.g. French *du, des, ès* for *de le, de les, en les*, Czech *nač, proč, doň,...* for *na co, pro co, do něj,...*, but the resulting unit is typically still just univerbised realisation of two otherwise separate words/morphs or it turns into an adverb by the process of grammaticalisation (the Czech case - *proč* meant originally *what for* and now it means *why* and most likely the case with the English adverbs as well, coming from some PIE *kʷo-* and spatial expression of location, direction, origin etc. like *wh-ere, wh-ence, wh-ither,*...).

Comment: Serving both as a preposition and as a pronoun is not necessarily contradictory, a word can simply have both functions. This is exactly the case with German wh-prepositions *womit*, *wodurch*, *worauf* etc.: They stand as a place holder for full-sense words and at the same time indicate the preposition that goes with the questioned word.

Comment: Your examples from French don't fit in this context: *du* and *des* are contractions for *de le* / *de les*, i.e. preposition + determiner, but they are not pronouns.

Comment: How is *Womit*, *Wodurch* or *Worauf* a preposition? Can it be followed by a noun? I certainly do not suspect so. If you do consider it one word (I have nothing against it), it is an adverb. It stands for adverbial constructions, it has adverbial distribution (develops a verb or VP in general). Regarding the French thing, yes, they are determiners, originating from Latin demonstrative pronouns (which is kind of not the point). Feel free to substitute with *duquel*, *desquels* etc. where you can see the pronominal/shifter element more clearly.

Comment: It has prepositional meaning because it indicates exactly the relation which is in a declarative sentence expressed by its "real" prepositional counterpart. The etymology *pre-position* doesn't mean that a preposition loses all of its prepositional meaning just because it is affected by syntactic movement and no longer standing right in front of the NP (which no longer exists as an NP because it is replaced by the question word, but *womit* means precisely *with what*, where *what* is the NP which just happens not to be realized this way in Gmn. question syntax, but referentially still there).

Comment: That you dub the resulting word syntactically as an adverb (I would agree on this) is due to its syntactic status (position, distribution etc), but the semantics is clearly adpositional (and at the same time pronominal), plus the original preposition is clearly visible in its w-counterpart.

Comment: About the French words: Yes, them being determiners and not (question) pronouns is why I think the example was somewhat out of context.

Comment: Preposition (or more precisely apposition) is a modifier of another word. The ample examples you gave are certainly not prepositions (although they are definitely spot-on for the question containing *wh-on* as an example), they just originate from a combination of one with another word. The same way *where, whither, whence* are not considered prepositions, even though part of their meaning is typically expressed by prepositions like *in, to, from*.

Comment: I didn't say that these words are syntactically to be classified as prepositions (if so, this was imprecise), only that they express a prepositoinal meaning.

Comment: I believe our problem is that I am questioning the question, which is specifically asking for wh-preposition but it wants actually something else (wh+preposition mergers).

Comment: Okay, I think I can agree on that ;)

Comment: Most modern analyses treat the preposition as the head of a "prepositional phrase," so it doesn't seem right to say that a preposition modifies a noun by definition.

Comment: @lemontree But syntactically *where* etc *do* behave like prepositions. They are unadverb-like in every way!

Comment: @Araucaria For example you cannot say "where the table did you put a toy?" when you want to know whether it is on the table or under it. At least in this particular sense where doesn't behave like a preposition. We can say "where did you put a toy" which is very similar to e.g. "Why did you eat a toy" where "why" is clearly adverbial.

Comment: @syntaxfairy Problem is that *wh-* words do not generally "replace" individual words. They replace phrases. So, for example, the word *who* will replace an entire NP, not a noun. Similarly  a *wh-* preposition "replaces" the whole preposition phrase, not just the preposition.

Comment: The fact that something can replace prepositional phrase does not mean it is a preposition. It can also replace another simple adverb (like *here* or *inside*). Prepositions have a very specific behavior, which is very different from this. Btw that was sort of one of the points in my answer.

Comment: @Eleshar *Here* and *inside* are also prepositions. See *CamGEL*! They do not behave syntactically like adverbs in any way.

Comment: *Inside* can be both adverb (*They are inside*) and a preposition (*They are inside the house*). *Here* does not behave like a preposition in any way (*They are here the house* is ungrammatical, exactly as Syntaxfairy pointed out for *where*). It is more precise to say that many prepositions in English behave like adverbs but not vice versa.

Comment: @Eleshar Maybe read up on some modern analyses of the preposition category. Here is why *here* is a prep: it can be modified by the specialised adverbs *right* and *straight*, it cannot be modified by the word *very*, it can be a locative complement of the verb *BE*, it can modify nouns. All of which shows it cannot be an adverb and that it is highly likely to be a prep.

Comment: Feel free to point me to them in this separate question (http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/20584/is-the-word-here-a-preposition/20601#20601). I would be very much interested in how other words I would label adverbs ("now", "aside", "abroad", "indoors") because they have pretty much the same preposition fit into this analysis.

Comment: @Araucaria: how can "here" modify a noun?  "This here dog"?

Comment: @mobileink Usually PPs post-modify nouns. So "The people here are very friendly" for example.

Comment: It seems you do not understand that **_prepositional phrase_ is not a _preposition_**. "here" has a distribution very similar to *prepositional phrase* but very different from a *preposition*, thus it is an adverb.

Comment: Is _correctly_ a preposition? It has also pretty similar distribution to some prepositional phrases: (_I do it **correctly**_ and _I do it **by the book**_). According to your logic (or logically... do we have another?), it would be a preposition the same way as you condider _here_ to be a preposition.

Comment: @Araucaria: i don't see why we should treat "here" as "modifying" any noun in "The people here are very friendly".  Compare "Here, the people are very friendly".  The use of "here" does influence the interp, but globally.  its an indexical.

Comment: @Araucaria: compare also "the people now are very friendly"

Comment: @mobileink Consider "When I was in London i didn't like the people here. Now I'me here I don't like the people in London". If you think about it carefully, the "I don't like the people here" in its most likely reading means something different to "Here, I don't like the people"

Comment: @Araucaria: nice!  let's be more explicit: i am now in Toronto. When I was in London, I di

Comment: @Araucari: (hit wrong button..  ) I didn't like the people here (in Toronro).   Now I'm here (still in Toronto), I don't like the people in London.

Comment: Yep, in the first instance *here* is clearly modifying *people*.In the second it's a complement of *be*. The third sentence, like the first has, a PP, *in London*, postmodifying *people*.

Comment: @Eleshar No that argument won't hold any water. Everybody knows that both PPs and AdvPs can modify both V and VP. So there's no argument there. Modifying a V or VP doesn't give you any indication of whether something is a prep or an adverb.

Comment: @mobileink Does that seem correct to you?

Comment: @Araucaria: i have to admit you've fed me some good food for thought. frankly i'm skeptical of the whole idea that some words "modify" other words;  i'm inclined to take a more global view. but i'll have to wrestle a bit more eoth your examples. thanks!

Comment: @Araucaria - but those are always prepositional **phrases**. My point is that _prepositional phrase is not the same as a preposition_; that _adverbs like 'here' have very similar distribution to prepositional **phrases** and **not** prepositions_ and that therefore _the word 'here' cannot be considered a preposition or word 'where' to be considered a wh-preposition_ because they certainly do not behave like one.

Comment: @Eleshar You're kind of  presupposing that prepositions always have NP complements. They don't. Generally speaking, excluding their distribution within XP's themselves, single word Xs generally have the same distribution as XPs. So you'll notice that Adverb Phrases - whether single word adverbs or not -can modify VPs. Similarly PP's - whether consisting of a single preposition or not - can also modify VPs. Your attempt to make here an adverb because it is a single word won't go through.

Answer (score 1):

Not only do many languages have *wh*-prepositions, English itself has at least two *wh*-prepositions. These are the words *when* and *where*, which, although classified as adverbs in traditional grammars, are recognised as prepositions by such grammars that allow for intransitive prepositions (for example, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, Huddleston & Pullum, 2002). The words *when* and *where* pass all of the tests for preposition-hood in English and none of the tests for being an adverb.

In relation to the sentence:

- I put the toy **on the table**.

... the preposition phrase *on the table* may be replaced by the interrogative preposition *where*:

- **Where** did I put the toy?

Comment: You replaced a *prepositional phrase*, not a mere *preposition*.  Prepositional phrases can be used adverbially.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is ***no***. If a language had a word like *whon?* standing for *what on?*, first, that word should, if anything, be described as a 'wh-**post**position', **not** as a 'wh-preposition', and secondly, and above all, if such a word existed in any language, its *wh+Q*-operator would have to 'question' **just the preposition *on***, **not its complement**, and the result would **not** be a 'partial' *wh+Q*-question, as in your *What did you put the toy on__?*, but a **polarity** (= a 'yes/no') question similar in meaning to what B replies to A in the following dialogue (say, between somebody who has arrived at his shop at 8 a.m., before his shop attendant, to find all the lights on and the shop attendant supposedly in charge of closing the shop and turning them all off on leaving the day before):

A: Do you know how you left the lights when you went home last night?

B: **On?** (= Did I leave them **on**? = a yes/no question)

The reason why presumably no human language has an interrogative word like *whon?* meaning *what-on* (< *on what?*, after 'P-stranding', a very rare feature of English) is that, as Katz & Postal in their (1964) book argued, a) the *wh+Q-* morpheme behaves as an interrogative **determiner**, b) what *wh+Q-* 'determines' is necessarily a **(pro)nominal** element (i.e., it **cannot** be a 'predicate', say a preposition - or a verb, for that matter), and c) what the *wh+Q-* operator correspondingly 'questions' is **the identity** of a) a human individual, as in *who* (approximately analysable as the surface form of *wh+he), or b) a non-human individual or substance, as in *what* (approximately the surface form of *wh+it), or c) a time interval, as in *when* (the surface form of *wh+en), or d) a place, as in *where* (< wh+ere), or e) a way of doing things - as in *how* (roughly, < *wh+(s)o)), or,finally, f) a reason for doing things, as in *why* (< wh+y), basically. In sum: what can carry an interrogative *wh+Q-* determiner is, at bottom, an NP/DP or an equivalent pro-form (which may happen to be a 'bound morpheme') denoting an 'entity' (an 'object' in Frege's sense), and, since a preposition does not denote an 'object', it **cannot** carry a *wh+Q* operator. (In this, I fully agree with Eleshar's answer above). Note that the (informal) Logical Forms of *Who wrote Hamlet?, When was Shakespeare born? Where was Shakespeare born?*, etc. are, respectively, Which x, x = a human being, Wrote (x, Hamlet), Which x, x = an interval of time, Was Born (Shakespeare, at/in x), and Which x, x = a place, Was Born (Shakespeare, in x)].

That classical analysis of interrogative *wh*-items has never really been challenged because several of the abstract bound morphemes on which it depends, particularly *-en, -ere, -ow,* and the *-y* of *why*, **do** occur elsewhere: in the corresponding *th*- 'deictics' *then, there, thus* (< *th + so < Middle English *swa*), and in the Early Middle English instrumental *thy* - roughly meaning 'for this' (note the contrast *wh + y* <> *th + y*).

Hence, I am sorry to have to say that neither German *wo+von, wor+auf, wo+mit*, etc., nor English *where+to, where+abouts*, etc. (nor their Dutch counterparts) are, in fact, examples of what the OP is interested in. To start with, because all of them would be **post**-positional, **not pre**positional expressions, but above all, because in **none** of such cases is the preposition itself 'questioned' by the *wh+Q-* operator. Spanish *por qué*, French *pourquoi*, Italian *per che*, etc. would at least be 'prepositional', but again, even in those cases, what the *wh+Q-* operator 'operates' on and 'questions' is **not** the preposition, but its '(pro)nominal' complement, whereas in the OP's hypothetical *wh+on* example the preposition has **no** complement and the *wh+Q*-operator would have to operate on the preposition itself (= a two-place 'predicate'), which, as far as I can tell, is impossible on conceptual grounds.

That does **not** mean that it is impossible for a predicate, in general, to be the **apparent** focus of a question, of course. In a yes/no question like *Did he **marry her**?* the VP *marry her* certainly counts, informationally speaking, as the focus of the question, but what the Q-operator really 'binds' (informally: 'questions, focuses on') in that clause is **not** the VP itself, but **the polarity variable** - ranging over the two t-type values {'true', 'false'} - associated with all clauses. Hence, the meaning of that question can be paraphrased as 'Is it true (or false) that he married her?', and, even more tellingly perhaps, the natural 'tag' that can be added to it is *didn't he* (or just *not*), as in *Did he marry her **or not/didn't he**?*, which clearly points to the clause's polarity value as the **real** focus of the Q-operator.

Interestingly, in Old English, presuppositionally 'marked' yes/no questions could still be introduced by the *wh+Q*-word *hw+aether* (a direct ancestor of our present-day *whether*) that could be transparently analyzed as the *wh+Q-* operator (spelt *hw-* at the time) plus a **determiner**, *either*, that introduced a proposition with the canonical structure of a positive statement (as in E. Closs Traugott's example [*HES*, p. 73] ***Hwaether*** ge nu secan gold on treowum? = 'Is it (really) true, or false (as I believe), that you now seek gold in trees?'), which made the logical structure of all OE questions, both polarity-focused and non-polarity-focused, look more uniform than it seems in Modern English (although, of course, we still have *whether*, possibly followed by *or not*, introducing 'indirect' polarity questions with the syntactic SVX form of statements (= propositions).

The only case in which a predicate can be the **real** focus of a Q operator, then, is in 'alternative questions' like *Did he **marry her** or **leave her**?*, but note that those are **neither** 'partial' **nor** 'polarity questions': they resolve, though, into **two** coordinated (contraposed) **polarity** questions, i.e., ***Did he marry her*** or **did he leave her?**, in each of which a separate Q-operator 'binds' the polarity variable (not the VP!) of the respective coordinate clause.