# Is the word "here" a preposition?

Tags: english, prepositions, word-classes, adverbs

In a [related question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/20270/do-there-exist-languages-with-wh-prepositions), I got entangled in a debate whether the word "here" (which I would classify readily as an adverb) is in reality a preposition. I am curious which modern analyses find syntactical similarities between "here" and words like "in, at, on, for, to" that they range them in the same category as well as the reasoning behind them.

Of course I am aware that many English prepositions are actually adverbs (i.e. they can stand on their own, without relation to a noun, and express for example a location on their own, e.g. "I am in").

Comment: Can you point to any of the 'more modern analyses' that you mention?

Comment: Actually that is the point of the question. So, no, I cannot, but I admit the question could be phrased better.

Comment: 'Of course I am aware that many English prepositions are actually adverbs' Many linguists (e.g. Pullum) would say that these are not adverbs but intransitive prepositions. Unlike other adverbs, 'in' cannot appear freely in other parts of the clause, for one thing. One fact that favours treating 'here' as a P is that you can add 'right' in front of it (right here), which you can do for many other prepositions (right at, right on, right in) but not with other parts of speech (#right book, *right eat, *right red).

Comment: "Here" is a prepositional phrase (PP), since it can be conjoined with another PP: "I sleep here and in the kitchen".

Comment: @Greg Lee: "I sleep soundly and in the kitchen".  Does that make "soundly" a preposition?

Comment: @mobileink, Well, by my reasoning, it would make "soundly" a PP.  That is not a happy conclusion, so I agree that my argument needs work.

Comment: 1) The phrase *I sleep soundly and in the kitchen* does not sound grammatical to me, it should be imho *I sleep soundly in the kitchen.* 2) I am after word class of "here" and not sure PP, which is an IC syntax term, is really on the same level of terminology but PPs in general have similar distribution as adverbs - PPs of location will corresponds to location adverbs, PPs of time will correspond to temporal adverbs, PPs of mode correspond to regular adverbs (_I do it **correctly**_ and _I do it **by the book**_).

Answer (score 4):

## "Here" is not a preposition per se.

By definition, prepositions come before a noun phrase (or determiner phrase) to create prepositional phrases:

> He was (in (the house)).
> They saw him (with (a knife)).

"Here" cannot do this.

> *He was here the house.
> *They saw him here a knife.

### However...

"Here" does act quite a bit like a prepositional *phrase*.

The typical way of testing where something lies in the syntax tree, is to apply a constituency test. [Wikipedia provides some examples.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_(linguistics)#Constituency_tests)

One common test is pro-substitution: if you can replace a sequence of words with a single pro-form, and get a grammatical result, then those words have the same category as the pro-form.

> The repairman was **here** earlier today.
> The repairman was **somewhere** earlier today.
> The repairman was **in the apartment** earlier today.
> *The repairman was **somewhere** *the apartment* earlier today.

Another test is coordination: if two phrases can be coordinated with "and", they're (almost always) the same type of phrase.

> There are dogs **inside and outside** the house.
> *There are dogs **inside and here** the house.
> There are dogs **inside the house and outside the house**.
> There are dogs **inside the house and here**.

These tests point to treating "here" as its own prepositional phrase.

Comment: I agree with this, *here* behaves syntactically like a prepositional phrase, and prepositional phrases have pretty similar distribution to adverbs: *He lives here* / *He lives in the house* / *He lives abroad*.

Comment: @Eleshar Wht you've just said is that a preposition behaves like a whole load of other prepositions. *Here* does not behave like any bona fide adverbs such as *locally*, for example.

Comment: I am happy to read a full-fledged answer comparing the distribution of word "here" against that of "full-fledged adverbs" (locally, abroad,...) and that of prepositions (at, onto,...) in a manner similar to the answer we are just commenting under.

Comment: Or in other words, *here* is a pro-preposition.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the popular *right* test that WavesWashSands refers to, evidence showing that *here* is a preposition - and **not** an adverb - comes from the fact that it can **post**modify nouns (cf. *The people **here** do not like changes*), whereas real adverbs cannot. If, on the other hand, *here* were of some other category, say an adjective or a noun, it should be able to **pre**modify other nouns, but, of course, it is **not** (cf. * *The **here** resources are insufficient*). Since a V, a Det, a Q, a Deg, etc., it cannot be either, analysing it as an **intransitive preposition** is virtually inevitable.

*Here* cannot by itself **in general** be analysed as a phrasal category (= PP), though, because it can be accompanied by its own dependents - not only *right*, but also PP's, as in *Here **in London**, housing is terribly expensive __*.

The fact that, in such an example, *Here in London* **can** be 'extracted' ( ?topicalized) **as a whole** from its VP/AP, but *in London* on its own cannot (cf. * ***In London***, housing is terribly expensive **here__**) constitutes further evidence that 1) *here in London* is a unitary constituent, and 2) that both *here in London* and *in London* are PP's, because, otherwise, the extraction of the PP complement *in London* would **not** violate Ross's 'A over A constraint' (or: 'minimality', under later approaches to movement) and should be grammatical (as are other PP complements extracted from non-PP's above them), but of course it is not - which follows nicely from the 'A-over-A constraint'.

Then, obviously, if *here in London* is a PP, *here* must itself be a P, because it is the head of that phrase, as shown, and phrases are endocentric, according to the X-Bar principles. That is a desirable outcome, because, if *here* is the head of the PP *here in London*, its non-extractability from it (cf. * ***Here***, housing is terribly expensive __ **in London**) needs no explanation, as heads of PPs (contrary to those of, e.g., VP's or AuxP's) can **never** be extracted, cf. * *In, I have never felt at home _ Berlin*.

That, by itself, is fairly strong evidence, I think, that *here* is, indeed, the head of the PP *here in Berlin* and, according to the endocentricity principle, a preposition, a conclusion that reinforces the evidence already presented in paragraph 1.

[The only other alternative (i.e., that the head of *here in London* were the preposition *in*, with *London* - its 'internal' argument - in its complement position, and *here* somewhere else, either as an adjunct or as a specifier) would not change things much, as we know from the arguments above that *here* cannot be adverbial, adjectival, nominal, etc., and must be prepositional anyway, but, apart from that, that possibility can be safely discarded for  different reasons: PP adjuncts like *here in London* are 'predicates' whose 'external' argument must be 'discharged' by the 'e(vent)' variable associated with the VP/V' they modify, and, therefore, they **cannot** project their second argument in their specifier position, because, if they did, they would become 'saturated' and would no longer be able to 'take' the 'e(vent)' argument associated with the 'VP' they must modify. The specifier slot of such PP adjuncts, therefore, must be **empty**, which excludes *here* from that hypothetical position. Hence, if the head of the PP *here in London* were the preposition *in*, *here* could at best be an 'adjunct' of *in* (one under the scope of *right*, cf. *right here in London* vs. * *here right in London*), but, if so, it would also have to be a **phrasal** category, i.e., a PP. PP pre-modifiers, however, are severely restricted in distribution; short of in (semi)-lexicalized expressions such as *an **out-of-print** book*), they practically never occur, and, in particular, locative PP's seem impossible to construe as modifiers of other locative P's like *in London*; in all the examples I can think of, the analysis must be different, in terms of **two** independent locative PP's].

In sum: there is rather solid evidence, I believe, in support of the claim that *here* is, categorially speaking, an **intransitive preposition**, and a 'head', although, of course, it will also function as a phrasal category whenever it occurs on its own (i.e., without the ?adjunct *right* or complements like *in London*). [I deliberately leave aside here the question whether *here* should also be analysed as a P, instead of a 'nominal' (a DP) in postpositional expressions like *hereafter*, etc.

Comment: Yes, _here_ can postmodify nouns (so can words like _wheresoever_, _abroad_ or _upstairs_ - are they prepositions too?). I am not, however, aware of any preposition that can, by itself, postmodify nouns. It is typically a PP that postmodifies nouns, not a preposition.

Comment: @ Eleshar Sorry, but your first question aims at a straw-man. Sure many non-prepositional words and phrases can postmodify N's, even ignoring reduced Rel Clauses, but 'abroad' may be an A or, also, a lexicalized PP (from 'a(<on)+broad'), i.e., a P (of course, an 'Adv', in lay dictionaries), just as 'up/downstairs' are lexicalized PPs (from 'up'/'down'+'stairs'), etc. Anyway, I explicitly acknowledged that 'here', categorially a P, is ALSO a PP when on its own, and there are PLENTY of P's that, apparently 'by themselves', postmodify N's, cf. 'the way in/out',' the day after/before', etc.

Comment: Could it not be that _in, out, after, before_ are actually adverbs rather than _here_ a preposition (which is, actually, exactly how prepositions came into existence historically)? For me, the prepositions prototypical function is to form a PP with an NP/DP. Sure, there are cases when this is not necessary for one reason or another. But _here_ and the like would apparently be the only case of a preposition that cannot do that while there are plenty of adverbs that can do things you use as proofs for the repositionality of _here_.

Comment: For example if due to endocentrism, _here in London_ indicates _here_ is a preposition because it is a head of a PP than surely the same applies for _(studying) **abroad** in France_ or _**yesterday** in the evening_? Speaking of _yesterday_, this can postmodify nouns as well (and not premodify, afaik).

Comment: @Eleshar Your conception of Ps is more in line with its conception in traditional grammar. That's fine, since Quirk et al. also apparently treat Ps this way, and classify *in*, *out*, *after*, as Advs as you do. But this leads to a less *elegant* description, since certain words which take no complement but otherwise share formal similarities with Ps are excluded from P. In a more modern conception of PoS, as Huddleston and Pullum wrote, a preposition is taken to be the head of a phrase (PP), and under this conception there's no principled basis for banning complementless Ps.

Comment: I agree that 'abroad' is a P. I think 'yesterday' would be a noun; we don't want to be claiming that 'month' is a noun in 'last month on the twenty-first'.

Comment: Nouns can be postmodified by adverbs as in examples like _Industrial action resulted in the **withdrawal indefinitely** of the vehicular ferry service_, and _A **shortage** of timber **internationally** led to a steep rise in prices_. In fact adverbial modifiers of nouns are restricted to post-head position.